# Purpose of internal storage in AWS RDS db.m6gd instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-rds, nvme, aws-graviton

What is the purpose of internal nvme storage on AWS ARM (Graviton2) RDS instaces (eg. db.m6gd)? I was able to select this class while creating RDS but can't find much info about internal storage purpose, configuration or life cycle.

[AWS RDS Graviton2 instances comparsion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O23VH.png)

I've created db.m6gd instance and imported database. FreeStorageSpace (which I belive corresponds to EBS) was decresed, FreeLocalStorage wasn't.

[RDS Free Storage Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56La.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to know. From what I have found myself I think it's related to this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-rds-optimized-reads-and-optimized-writes/ _"Amazon RDS Optimized Reads achieve faster query processing by placing temporary tables generated by MySQL on NVMe-based SSD block storage that is physically connected to the host server"_